# Отображается phpinfo() Хотя оно выключенно

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
    // error_reporting( E_ERROR );
    require 'connection.php';
    // require 'db.php';
    require 'login.php';
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    $data = $_POST;
    if ( isset($data['do_signup']) )
    {
        //здесь регистрируем
        $errors = array();
        if($data['name'] == '')
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите имя вашего персонажа';
        }
        if( trim($data['mail']) == '')
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите Email!';
        }
        if($data['age'] == '')
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите возраст Вашего персонажа';
        }
        if( $data['password'] == '')
        {   
            $errors[] = 'Введите Пароль';
        }
        if( $data['password_1'] != $data['password'] )
        {   
            $errors[] = 'Пароли не совпадают';
        }
        if( R::count('accounts', "name = ?", array($data['name'])) > 0 )
        {   
            $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким ником уже зарегистрирован.';
        }
        if( R::count('accounts', "mail = ?", array($data['mail'])) > 0 )
        {   
            $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким Email уже зарегистрирован.';
        }
        if( empty($errors) )
        {
            // Создаём соль
            $password = $data['password']; // Password
            $password = hash("md5", $password); // Хэшируем
            //Всё хорошо, регистрируем
            // Выдаём рандомный скин по гендеру
            if ($sex == 1)
            {
            $skin = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // Мужские скины
            $data['model'] = $skin[array_rand($skin)];
            }
            if ($sex == 2)
            {
            $skin = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // Женские скины
            $data['model'] = $skin[array_rand($skin)];
            }
            //Передача данных в Базу Данных
            $query = "INSERT accounts SET name ='".$data['name']."', password=".$password.",mail='".$data['mail']."', sex=".$data['sex'].", model=".$data['model'].", last_ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', join_ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            // Тут будет отправка E-Mail сообщения на почту.

            $to = $data['mail'];
            $subject = "Portland RolePlay";
            $message = 'Поздравляем Вас с регистрацией на сервере Portland Role Play!\n Ваш игровой аккаунт успешно создан!\nЧтобы начать играть, добавьте наш сервер в клиент SA:MP! ';
            mail($to, $subject, $message);

            // Тут будет отправка E-Mail сообщения на почту.
            $errors = 1;
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Увлекательный проект сетевой игры GTA San Andreas Multiplayer (SAMP). Тысячи игроков и море фана ждут тебя, заходи прямо сейчас!">
    <title>PortlandRP : Регистрация</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_fonts.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="menu-toggle"><span></span></div>
    </div>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <div class="logo"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Главная</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Форум</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                        <li><a href="donate.html">Донат</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#login">
                        <div class="nav__ucpbtn">Личный кабинет</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main id="panel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel-form1">
                        <p align="center"><h1 align="center">Регистрация</h1></p>
                        <div align="center">
                        <form method="POST" action="signup.php" class="signupform">
                            <div class="nick">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Придумайте NickName в формате Name_Surname" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$+_" value="<?php echo @$data['name']; ?>"><br>
                            </div>
                            <input type="email" name="mail" id="name" placeholder="Введите Ваш E-Mail" value="<?php echo @$data['mail']; ?>"><br>
                            <select name="sex" id="name">
                                <option disabled>Выберите пол Вашего персонажа</option>
                                <option value="1">Мужской</option>
                                <option value="2">Женский</option>
                            </select><br>
                            <input type="text" name="age" id="name" placeholder="Введите возраст Вашего персонажа"><br>
                            <input type="text" name="promo" id="name" placeholder="Введите промокод(Если имеется)"><br>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="name" placeholder="Придумайте пароль"><br>
                            <input type="password" name="password_1" id="name" placeholder="Повторите пароль"><br>
                                <button id="signupbutton" type="submit" name="do_signup">Зарегистрироваться</button>
                        </form>
                            <div style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">
                            <!-- Тут будет выводиться результат (ошибка или положительно) -->
                            <? echo array_shift($errors);
                            ?>
                            </div>
                            <div style="color: green; font-size: 20px;">
                            <? if ($errors == 1) {
                                echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированны!";
                            }
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <section id="vk">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Мы ВКонтакте</h2>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="social">
                        <h3>Присоединяйтесь к нам!</h3>
                        <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $.ajax({  
            url: 'http://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?gid=samp_portland&fields=members_count', // вместо 65762432 указываем свой ID 
            dataType: "jsonp", // тип получаемых данных
            success:function(e){ 
                $('#vkontakte_count').html(e.response[0].members_count) // выводим получаемый результат
            }  
        }); 
    });
</script>
                        <span id="vkontakte_count"></span>
                        <img src="images/socialpeap.png" alt="Мы ВКонтакте">
                        <a href="https://vk.com/samp_portland" target="_blank">
                            <div class="vk__socbtn">Вступить в группу</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                    <div class="ftlogo"></div>
                    <p>© 2018 PORTLAND  – Мультиплеер GTA San Andreas в режиме RolePlay</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                    <div class="vctrmyrov"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>


                <!-- Код авторизации -->

            <!-- Код авторизации -->
    <!-- Login -->
    <div class="modal" id="login">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h2>Авторизация</h2>
            <a class="close-modal" href="#">X</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="nick">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваш ник">
                </div>
                <div class="pass">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Ваш пароль">
                </div>
                <div class="signin">
                    <input type="submit" name="do_login" value="Войти в аккаунт">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Login -->

    <!-- navigation -->
    <div class="mobile-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.html">Новости</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Форум</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Начать играть</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Пополнить счёт</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Игровой мир</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="auth.html" class="mobilenav_button green">Авторизоваться</a>
    </div>

<!-- здесь будет отображаться количество подписчиков -->
<span id="vkontakte_count"></span>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>$('.carousel').carousel();</script>
    <script src="js/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mobile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: значит вы его подулючаете в других частях. Смотрите подключаемые файлы - `require 'connection.php';`  и др.

Comment: нет в connection.php не подключаю в login.php тоже

Comment: проверьте все require. У вас оно не одно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте все `require`. У вас оно не одно. Также попробуйте в файле в самом начале написать `exit('ooppps')`. Если увидите текст и не будет `phpinfo`, значит ниже где-то подключаете. Так и ищите - двигая `exit('ooppps')` в разные места. Если же всё равно `phpinfo` есть, значит вы что-то не то делаете. Значит вы вообще не тот код выполняете.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое оказывается он в login.php был я не заметил